# Angular auto complete with $resource

Tags: angularjs

I am starting a new project and looking for an auto complete plugin for angular that works with $resource. I've browsed github and found projects like ngAutoComplete, I am a little weary to try this before it seems the last activity on the project was 2 years ago.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is off-topic, but I'll suggest [typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Comment: Another alternative (used by my) is https://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead